# Parallax background has white borders on the side

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, parallax

We're trying to add a parallax background to our website, but it has an annoying white border around the image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt0Pf.jpg).

We've tried everything and don't know what to do. We couldn't find an issue with the CSS or HTML. We're thinking it's an issue with margins but there isn't anything that could be affecting it.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"><!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <title>
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="sidenav" id="sideNav">
    </div>


    <section class="background headpage">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>T K S - F O U N D A T I O N S</h1>
        </div>
    </section>


    <div onclick="openNav()" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer">
        <h2>&#9776;</h2>
    </div>
    <script>
              function openNav() {
              document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "250px";
              }

              function closeNav() {
              document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "0";
              }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-family: "Lato";
    height: 100%;
}
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #38afff;
}
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .sidenav a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
.background {
    position: relative;
}
.background .container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.background .container h1 {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lato";
}
.background .container h2 {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 105%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.headpage {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;

    background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.212), rgb(0, 0, 0)), url('https://i.imgur.com/0KzSXdk.jpeg');
    position: absolute;
  }
```

Comment: Please add some code to help you and not github link.See the How to [Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
please check this below link, i tested in codepen
```

https://codepen.io/kapil00/pen/jOPQrpg

Answer (score 0):

I think setting margin: 0; on body would fix the white border.

Comment: But you need to do som more to get any parallax fx going.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't seem to work. user3337667 (what an amazing name) had the correct answer.

Comment: Grate that you fond a solution. Maybe I misunderstood what you tried to achieve. But the white border disappears on my test: https://codepen.io/schoien/pen/xxGQPxG